# how to access objectAtIndex:indexpath.row xcode?

Tags: row, ibaction, uipicker

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:

(NSInteger)component {

if(thePickerView == self.countryPicker){

        self.countryLbl.text = [self.responseArray objectAtIndex:row];

       }
}

- (IBAction)countryDoneBtn:(id)sender {

    // Picker first row selected on done button

   [self.countryLbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.responseArray 

objectAtIndex:[self.countryPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]]]];

    [self myViewDown:self.countryView];

    [self.durationView removeFromSuperview];

    //[post selectState:[self.responseArray objectAtIndex:row ]];
}
```

i want to do this "`[post selectState:[self.responseArray objectAtIndex:row]];`"

but can't access "`objectAtIndex:row`" here in this "`- (IBAction)countryDoneBtn:(id)sender`"

method.

Please friend help me how can i access the row from this IBAction

Thanks in advance need your help i'm new in iphone development

Comment: take one global variable and set the value of the picker selected row and use that variable.

Comment: Why don't you use the [self.countryPicker selectedRowInComponent:0] instead of row?

Answer (score 0):

The *row* variable is not available because the *row* you are looking for is only passed in the delegate method didSelectRow:inComponent of the picker view.

Based on you are trying to do, you can still get the selected row of the picker with the method *selectedRowInComponent*, which you have already used to set the text of the countryLbl.

So, just use the same method to get the object from your responseArray:

```
NSInteger selectedRow = [self.countryPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
[post selectState:[self.responseArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow]];
```